# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not EntityAnnotation

Tags: python

I am using the Google vision api to extract the text from an image and I also want to store this text in a .txt file.

Whenever I use `f.write(text.description)` I get:

> UnicodeEncodeError

With `f.write(text)` it gives me:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not EntityAnnotation

`f.write(text.description.encode("utf-8"))` gives me:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write a variable of type `EntityAnnotation` which is a Json Object and not a `str`. Check out [EntityAnnotation - Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#entityannotation), on the position tab you can find out how the structure is made. Probably you are trying to write some information allocated in it.

Remember you can write the whole object by making it a string `str(json_objt)` or using 
`json.dumps(json_obj)` in order to serialize json_obj to a JSON formatted `str`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `text.description` contains characters which cannot be encoded in your filesystem's default encoding.  This can be the case on Windows machines where the default filesystem encoding is cp1252, but is also possible on other platforms, depending on how they have been configured.

You can get around this by specifying a different encoding when you open the file - utf-8 is usually a good choice.

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text.description)
```

Note that you will need to specify the encoding if you try to read from the file:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    description = f.read()
```